# Como instalar versões antigas do PHP abaixo de php 5.5?

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

Ouvi dizer que no *Ubuntu* contém pacotes já disponíveis para instalação, pois bem, confirmei e realmente é verdade, instalei só que veio com *php5.5*, eu preciso do *php5.2.17*, para instalação do meu **vBulletin**, como posso instalar?

**Apache 2.2.21
PHP 5.2.17
MySQL 5.5.21**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No site do [vBulletin](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/vb5_system_requirements) fala que é PHP 5.3.7 pra cima.
Essa tua versão deve estar desatualizada.

Eu tive esse mesmo problema, pois as versões antigas do PHP usam bibliotecas que não estão mais disponíveis nas novas versões do Ubuntu.

Você pode usar uma versão antiga de Ubuntu ou Linux que aceita o PHP 5.3

Ou baixar do [site do PHP](http://php.net/releases/) compilar e instalar:

```
wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.17.tar.bz2
tar -xvf php-5.2.17.tar.bz2
cd php-5.2.17
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Mas como instalo versões abaixo de php 5.5 ? já formatei o computador duas vezes tentando instalar... Lembrando que só tenho licença do vBulletin 4.2.2 :( ele só pega na versão php 5.2

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta... Vamos votar galera!

Comment: Dei +1 pela edição. :-)